# how to implement gem fedex to track a shipment

Tags: rubygems, fedex

hello i was wondering how to implement the 'fedex' gem after seeing added the credentials and the function x

```
results = fedex.track(:tracking_number => "1234567890123")
# => [#<Fedex::TrackingInformation>]

# Pull the first result from the returned array
#
tracking_info = results.first

tracking_info.tracking_number
# => "1234567890123"

tracking_info.status
# => "Delivered"

tracking_info.events.first.description
# => "On FedEx vehicle for delivery"
```

i don't know how to show json